# Showing only an item from a webpage in a webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I've a problem,i have to show this component of a webpage

```
  <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">

  <h1></h1>
  <p class="testoprezzo">0.5826 </p>
```

But i don't know how to do it (i'm definitely an Android Newbie),here's my try

```
   final WebView webview = view.findViewById(R.id.WebViewValore);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()  {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByTagName('p class')[0].style.display=;" +
                    "})()");
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl("https://MyWebPage.net/");
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want to show that html code in a WebView ?

Comment: I want to show only the number,but it change and i need to download it before show it i think